# GitHub commit contributions not reflecting on profile despite successful push

Tags: authentication, github, version-control, git-push, personal-access-token

**Description:**
Despite successful pushes using a personal access token, I'm having trouble with my GitHub commit contributions not showing on my profile. The commits are pushed to the main branch, but the green dots on my GitHub profile are not updating.

**Steps Taken:**

1. Used `git push origin main` with a personal access token.
2. The verified local branch is on the main branch.
3. No error messages during the push.

Why do my commit contributions not reflect on my GitHub profile, and how can I fix this?